# How do you use an existing completion for a function in zsh?

Tags: git, zsh, tab-completion

If I write a zsh function like this

```
function git_checkout_with_selecta() {
  if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    git checkout `git branch --no-merged | selecta`
  else
    git checkout "$@"
  fi
}
alias gco='git_checkout_with_selecta'
```

How can I apply the same tab completions that I have for 'git checkout' to the alias for the function 'gco'?

Answer (score 7):

```
compdef _git gco=git-checkout
```

This will use the `_git` completion function, and sets `git-checkout` as the service/sub-command.

Comment: On zsh 5.3 this returns `zsh:12: command not found: ___git_checkout_main`

Comment: @Lucas have you tried a more recent Zsh version?  (it works for me on 5.6.2, and I assume given the age of my answer that was an older already)  Might be related to autoloading etc.  What is the context around line 12 from your example?

Comment: The problem I was seeing was using `compdef` directly on a function instead of an alias, switching to using `compdef` on the alias seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
compdef gco=git
```

If your completer triggers on git.